# Converting string "ex: PT20H" to time in android

Tags: android, string, time, time-format

I'm developing an android application.
This time format returns to me as a string from the database -->"PT20H" and I want to convert it to the following format --> "20:00".
Any ideas??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the characters mean?  You likely need to write your own parser, since that doesn't look like any sort of standard I know about.

Comment: If you can tell me some kind of pattern for the numbers/ letters that you get from the DB, I'd be happy to write up a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called parsing a time string. Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Its seems like you've got some plain text that isn't informative, being the PT and the H. That is, if all your times are whole hours only (eg "PT20H23M" for 20:23 does not occur. I believe the pattern to use should be "'PT'H'H'"
That is PT (between quotes to signify text to ignore, then the hour (symbol H) and then H between quotes again because it is to be ignored.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'PT'H'H'");
Date theDate = sdf.parse("PT20H");
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m");
String newFormattedString = newFormat.format(theDate);
```